# Z-index not working in FF

Tags: html, position, z-index

I'm struggling with a template and a picture that should overlay another div.

In Chrome it's working, but it's not in FF. Somehow my z-index isn't working. Could anyone help me?

The site is www.mijneigending.nl. The A-logo should overlap the slider as is the case in Chrome.

greetings Linda

Comment: Please use JSFiddle or something like it instead of providing a link to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

to your style.css file. Works in IE. Should work anywhere else.